# Delete an item from an array in a Laravel session

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

How can I delete only a single item from an array in Laravel with Sessions. When I try to do it now with `Session:pull`, it just deletes the whole session object with key `estate.id` and with all the items in the array. I want to match only the object that has the same id as the id received from the input.

**Simplified code**

```
$estateId = Input::get('id', null);

if ($processType == "add") {
    Session::push('estate.id', $estateId);
   }
else {
  if (in_array($estateId, $data)) {
     $value = Session::pull('estate.id', $estateId);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can set the index same as the id and use it to delete.

Comment: @Sougata Index is not the same as the ID, the array output looks like `Array ( [0] => 83968 [1] => 97798 )`

Comment: So store it like - `Array ( [83968] => 83968 [97798] => 97798 )`, instead of `push`.

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. Is this not possible with the built in Laravel service

Comment: It is possible. After all it is an array. Think, you will definitely get the way.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel Session service doesn't offer a built in method to remove a value from an array, but there is a workaround you can do with:

```
Session::put('key', array_diff(Session::get('key'), ['value']));
```